# How can i show colorful cifar10 images using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to show generated images from cifar10 dataset in a figure(i have generated images usin generative adversarial networks. but the color of images are kind of green!

```
cntr = 0
        for e in plot_epochs:
            if i == e:
                if row_counter < 10:
                    for q in range(10):
                        z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (100, cfg.z_shape))
                        imgs = mySess.run(generator, feed_dict={phZ: z})
                        imgs = imgs * 0.5 + 0.5
                        axs_result[q, row_counter].imshow(imgs[cntr, :, :, 0], cmap="viridis")
                        axs_result[q, row_counter].axis('off')
                        cntr += 1
                    row_counter += 1

            fig_result.savefig("results/worker_%d_results/%d.png" % (nID, nID))
```

[image]

How can i fix the color issue of images?

Comment: change colormap

Comment: You used `cmap="viridis"`, which is *kind of green* indeed. Use a different colormap if you don't like that; available colormaps are at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html